# How do I install Zimbra Desktop?

Tags: unity, email

I'd like to install Zimbra Desktop but I'm worried about picking logical installation locations and how it will integrate with the Unity desktop. If it doesn't appear in the Messaging Menu there isn't much I can do about that, but what about the launcher?

There doesn't seem to be PPA or similar resource. These instructions for 10.10 seem complete: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-zimbra-desktop-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick.html

> 6 If you would, accept the default directori where it install 
>   /opt/zimbra/zdesktop

Is this the logical location for Ubuntu?

> 9 Now you’ll be asked about where to install files, for example: 
>   Home//.zdesktop

Sounds right. Is it?

> 10 And then you’ll be asked about the path where to locate the icon where you’ll launch Zimbra, for example: 
>   /home//Desktop

How about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just installed latest Zimbra desktop in Ubuntu 11.10. The following procedure should be the same for 10.10 and 11.04.

1. Download the compressed file from Zimbra website.
2. Open Nautilus as root. You can do this by running the following command in a terminal: `gksudo nautilus`
3. Navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded and decompress it.
4. Go inside the decompressed folder and run the install.pl (double click it and run in terminal). Accept the license, and hit enter to the default location of the files `/opt/zimbra`. **Note:** Do not install the desktop to root user.
5. close Nautilus as root, and open a normal Nautilus session.
6. Navigate to `/opt/zimbra/zdesktop/linux`
7. Run user-install.pl, by double cliking it and running it in terminal.
8. Accept the first folder to install your files `/home/user/zdesktop`.
9. The second folder I change it to only `/home/user` so I can have an accessible icon and can add it to the Unity launch by dragging from the dash and dropping it in the launcher.
10. Run zimbra.